Dialogflow ES, detecting intent without executing webhook
Is there a way to send a request to Dialogflow ES without executing the fulfillment/webhook if it is activated?
I just want to know which intent  (intent.displayName) would have been hit.
Thanks for your help
const request = {
  'session': this.#session(),
  'queryInput': {
    'text': {
      'text': message,
      'languageCode': 'en-US'
    }
  },
};

const detectIntent= await this.sessionClient.detectIntent(request);

The method "detectIntent" returns the result AFTER the fulfillment/webhook has been executed.
This is not what I am looking for.

I have found a solution that works for me and I would like to share it with you.
I send a parameter to the method detectIntent inside the header. This is to prevent the called webhook from being executed.
 if (options.dry_run) {
    request.queryParams.webhookHeaders['dry-run'] = true;
}

In the webhook itself, I request this parameter in the header. If it is set, the webhook is aborted.
if (req.headers?.['dry-run']) {
    res.status(code).end();
}

I now get the response from the intent from the detectIntent method, which actually would have executed the webhook and sent the response.
